# In which folder is my android application?

Tags: android, installation

I created an Android app which is storing some info on the database. I copied .apk file to a folder, clicked on it, it was installed and the app is working. But I cannot find in which folder the app is is located - I want to backup the database. Any ideas?

Thanks,
zb

Answer (score 0):

The app will normally be installed in `/data/app` directory - it would usually be just the copy of your APK, although not always.  The databases, unless you explicitly specified a different location in your code, will be in

```
/data/data/your.package.name/databases
```

The package name will be something like `com.yourcompany.appname`.

Note that backing the data by copying the databases is not the right way to backup your files.  Use android backup instead.  Also, unless your phone is rooted, you may not be able to get to these databases.

Answer (score 0):

Zalek 
 Here the location for the app to be searched

MyApp/myapp/build/outputs/apk/myapp-debug.apk

Note: "MyApp" is your project name of your app. I just take an example as myapp

Comment: I still cannot find it.
My package name is: com.example.mydictionary
My app name is: MyDictionary
I created a folder \MyDictionary where I moved the .apk file.
The app is working. In my Samsung8 phone I have folder \Android\data
I have the folder \Android\data on the internal memory and on the SD card.
I searched both folders and their subfolders for the string "mydictionary" - but did not find anything.
Since the app is working in must be located in some place.
zb